# Youtube API's maximum number of video uploads per day

Tags: api, youtube, upload, limit

We are building an app with a video upload functionality. We were wondering if we could use a Youtube account to upload all of our user videos. They should only be accessible via our app... we don't mind if ads show up while viewing them.

If the app grows, we're looking at potential thousands of uploads per day.

Does Youtube support this? If a few videos get flagged, will the "master" account be shut down?

Finally, if Youtube is the not right choice, do you have any recommendation? We would like to avoid hosting them as much as possible... Since streaming large amounts of videos is an enormous challenge for a start up.

Thank you!

Comment: YT provides 10,000 quota per day and each inserts costs 400. So 10k/400 = 25 videos per day.

Comment: now insert cost is 1600

Answer (score 6):

Some information on the video uploads:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert

> This method supports media upload. Uploaded files must conform to
>   these constraints: Maximum file size: 128GB Accepted Media MIME types:
>   video/*, application/octet-stream

You can get the qouta information here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota

> Projects that enable the YouTube Data API have a default quota
>   allocation of 1 million units per day, an amount sufficient for the
>   overwhelming majority of our API users.

...

> Different types of operations have different quota costs.
>
> A simple read operation that only retrieves the ID of each returned
>   resource has a cost of approximately 1 unit. A write operation has a
>   cost of approximately 50 units. A video upload has a cost of
>   approximately 1600 units.

Yes, youtube can block API access, not only on flagged videos, but at any time as described here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms/api-services-terms-of-service#termination

> 24.2 Termination by YouTube. Notwithstanding anything to the contrary, YouTube reserves the right to (i) suspend or terminate access to, or
>   use of, any aspects of the YouTube API Services by you, your API
>   Client(s) and those acting on your behalf), and (ii) terminate the
>   Agreement (or any portion thereof), as applied to any specific user or
>   API Client, category of users or API Clients, or all users or API
>   Clients at any time. For example, we may need to exercise such rights
>   in instances of your breach of this Agreement, court order, when we
>   believe there to have been misconduct or conduct which may create
>   potential liability for YouTube or its Affiliates. Although we will
>   try to give you reasonable notice, we have no obligation to do so.

Comment: love how YouTube changed the "1 million" to 10,000 and had the nerve to leave the `amount sufficient for the overwhelming majority of our API users`